# How to call a kuu from a shell script

Tags: shell

I want to kuu to an account which requires a password, but I want to do this inside a shell script. How can I provide the password from the shell script?

Comment: What is `kuu`? A command-line tool? This post and the SO version are the second and third results on Google; the first makes it sound like a varient of `su`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `expect` tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sudo instead of kuu, that way you would not need to store password in clear text…

Comment: It'd be awesome if you could explain how this might be accomplished with `sudo`.